# wave equation on a circular domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the wave equation for the displacement 
$$\text{u(r,$\theta $,t)}$$ in a 
circular domain $$\text{0 $<$ r $<$ a, -$\pi $ $<$ $\theta $ $<$ $\pi $}$$

How do I use the separation of variables on this problem to show that this equation reduces to 3 ODE's, 2 of which are eigenvalue problems?

Comment: can you write the wave equation in polar co-ords if so show the equation.

Comment: @Chinny84 I know the wave equation is of the form

$$U_{\text{tt}}=C^2U_{\text{xx}}$$ But I really have no idea how to put this in polar-form

Comment: actually you would have a canonical form $U_{tt}=C^2\left(U_{xx}+U_{yy}\right)$ but in any case you use the change of variable $$x\to r\cos \theta,\\y\to r\sin \theta.$$. Also, there are masses amount of information on the wave equation in polar co-oords.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you. I realised!

Comment: Great stuff. Hope you sort it out.